# Java can't create file unless admin even with permissions set for everyone

Tags: java, windows, file, filesystems, user-permissions

So I am working on Java app that does some operations with files, app only works when ran with admin privileges, problem is that app needs to be used on bunch of machines by clients that don't (and should not) have admin credentials.

```
try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {

            Files.copy(in, Paths.get("allDocs.zip"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        }
```

Exception gets thrown on Files.copy line: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: allDocs.zip

Thing is, I tried putting files in Public folder, in user home dir, in AppData, in app instalation dir, in folder for which I set that every user have full control... I always get java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException unless i run program with admin account. Why is this happening? If user that starts Java  process have permissions to write why Java process can't? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you’re writing the file in Public, user.home, AppData, etc.?  Your code just puts the file in the current directory.

Comment: @VGR yes I'm sure because if I run it as admin files get created in those places

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the file?

Comment: @VGR actually you were right. Post it as answer if you want. Thanks for help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes I checked, problem was the files and folders were created on the route set in route constant, but there was one hardcoded route which I missed. I inherited this code base and it's not of greatest quality.

Comment: For future reference, Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) is useful for this sort of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just writes the file in the current directory.  Use absolute paths to avoid this;  for instance:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
Files.copy(in, Paths.get(home, "allDocs.zip"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```